# org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: On-the-fly creation of JCache Cache objects is not supported in HIBERNATE

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache, second-level-cache

I'm using **hibernate 5.3.3, hibernate-ehcache 5.3.1 & ehcahe 3.2. with Java 8.**

I added the following configurations in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

I added the following annotations in in my entity class as well.

```
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
```

I searched on the internet but I did not find any answers for the follwowing exception.

```
`Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: On-the-fly creation of JCache Cache objects is not supported [default-update-timestamps-region]
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory.createCache(EhcacheRegionFactory.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory.getOrCreateCache(EhcacheRegionFactory.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.EhcacheRegionFactory.createTimestampsRegionStorageAccess(EhcacheRegionFactory.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.support.RegionFactoryTemplate.buildTimestampsRegion(RegionFactoryTemplate.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.EnabledCaching.<init>(EnabledCaching.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceInitiator.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceInitiator.java:30)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 21 more`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EhCacheRegionFactory is used to connect to Ehcache 2.x. You said you are using Ehcache 3.2, which is good. But it also means you should use a `org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory` to configure it.