# I am working with hibernate 5.3.1 but its showing On-the-fly creation of JCache Cache objects is not supported

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I am adding following jars

1. ehcache-2.10.3
2. hibernate-ehcache-5.3.1.Final
3. slf4j-api-1.7.7

I tried this with java 11

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go from memory. My first feeling would be that you are actually having Ehcache 3 in your classpath. This error normally occurs when you are trying to access a cache that wasn't created upfront. This used to be forbidden because the spontaneously created cache would have a random configuration. So we prefered preventing the creation. I do not remember this applying to Ehcache 2.

It might also be that you are using a JCache implementation that was meant to be used with Ehcache 3. This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113502/org-hibernate-cache-cacheexception-on-the-fly-creation-of-jcache-cache-objects) can help out.